# Webgrid SelectedLink URL Issue

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I have a `webgrid`. When selecting the ID column it displays a partial view with further details on that item.

It was initially working fine but lately a strange timestamp has appeared when pressing/highlighting the ID link;

`localhost:xxxxx/Page?selectedRow=1&__swhg1234567890` for example.

The '`&__swhg1234567890`' needs removed but I have no idea why its appearing in the `URL` and causing the the `WebGrid` links to not work.

It is all handled in Index.cshtml

```
var grid = new WebGrid(Model,
        canPage: true,
        canSort: true,
        rowsPerPage: 20,
        defaultSort: "projNo",
        selectionFieldName: "selectedRow",
        ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");


<div id="gridContent">
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "altRow",
    selectedRowStyle: "selectRow",
    columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column("ID", "ID", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.ID)),
                          grid.Column("Text", "Text", format: (item) => item.Text == null ? string.Empty : item.Text),
            grid.Column(header: "Actions", format: (item) => new HtmlString(Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.id }).ToString() + Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.id }).ToString()))))

</div>

@{
    IMS.Models.Entities.Page page= new IMS.Models.Entities.Page();
}

@if (grid.HasSelection)
{

    page= (IMS.Models.Entities.Page)grid.Rows[grid.SelectedIndex].Value;

        <div id="descHead">
         Detail goes here
        </div>
        <br />
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How are making ID a link, can you post that code?

Comment: @AnilKumar
grid.Column("ID", "ID", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.ID) 

{
    IMS.Models.Entities.Page page = new IMS.Models.Entities.Page();
}

if (grid.HasSelection)
{

    survey = (IMS.Models.Entities.Page)grid.Rows[grid.SelectedIndex].Value;

Comment: You also need to show logic of item.GetSelectLink(item.ID); please add this to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was an AJAX problem. Removing the unused 'ajaxUpdateContainerId' parameter corrected the problem.